# Stop caching or force refresh of a scraped webpage result VBS

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Having an issue with a script I've cobbled together which essentially should just hit a .asp url, retrieve and tally the results.

The reason being we have servers behind an F5 and have no other way of alerting if these are down or not. Hitting the .asp url returns the server name, and if I tally it up over ten minutes I can alert if one count is 0.

The script does what it's supposed to but is obviously caching the result somewhere and I can't figure out where. Each run will give a full count to either A or C.

*Apologies, this isn't my exact code but it's pretty close. :)

```
dim stroutput,counta,countc
do while timer <50

url = "my.url.asp"
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, 0
xmlhttp.send ""
stroutput= xmlhttp.responsetext
if stroutput = "valueA" then counta = counta + 1
if stroutput = "valueB" then countb = counta + 1
wscript.sleep 1200

loop
msgbox counta
msgbox countb
Set xmlhttp = Nothing
set stroutput = nothing
```

**Things I've tried.**

I tried to change the CreateObject value to WinHTTP which failed a `'stroutput= xmlhttp.responsetext with 'data is not ready yet' . Couldn't resolve this.

Tried to involve a Now() and Timer() function to the URL so it'd always be a fresh value meaning the script had to go to the server to check but I was getting, I think, a Type Mismatch error? Couldn't resolve this either.

Also tried to create a shell to clear IE history, cache etc but I think I was well off track with that. :)

I have read a few questions on here which seem to be roughly the same but couldn't implement the advice.

Wonder if I was on the right track or am missing something obvious?

TIA for any help folks. :)

Comment: Force the asp page to re-validate it's cache on the server, not the client.

Comment: `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` is for web server to web server communication. `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` is for client to server. `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` is separate to IE so clearing IE's cache won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. How would I do that Lankymart? I'm not in control of the server, so what would I need to code to re-validate server side?

Comment: Or, is this something that can be configured server side? A timeout or similar? 

Bar in mind it's an F5 in front of 2 web servers.

Comment: @Moominboy you're not in control of `my.url.asp`? If you were you can set the caching headers as part of the server response.

Comment: Think I've found the relevant info here (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/response.html)

Setting the cache header to no-cache would force a re-validation?

Comment: Thanks again for your time folks. The issue isn't with the asp file @Lankymart , I checked and the headers are set no-cache. The problem is the F5 has session persistence on it, based on my source IP. 

Doubt there's anyway I can get round this client side.